# Is there a table listing contributed modules that have been ported to Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

To date I have found no quick way to determine which Drupal 6 contributed modules have been ported to Drupal 7.

Do you know of one, such as an automatically updated table that provides this critical site-building and version-selection information?

Answer (score 0):

There is the D6 [Upgrade Status Module](http://drupal.org/project/upgrade_status/) that will list what modules installed on your system have modules in the D7+ versions of Drupal.